# Allow players to automatically "Jump" from level X to level X+n

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I have a server that is configured in such a way that when you hit level 83 you should be granted enough levels to get you to level 120.

I have set in the Game.ini that the level requirements of level 84 to level 119 is 0XP.

This worked for me and a couple of my friends. We were all level 83+ at the time when I have made this change and this worked like a charm.

However, today a couple of the new guys on the server hit level 83 and they are stuck at that level with 232570/232570 XP. I've tried giving them XP manually...but they stay at the 232570XP not jumping to level 84 which would enable them to automatically jump to level 120.

So long story short, clearly setting the XP requirement to 0 XP is not the proper solution...anyone knows how I can solve this?

[Update]

I have changed the Game.ini settings so that the XP Requirements from level 84 to level 120 would be 1 XP per level. Did not work, my guys are stuck at level 83 and it shows their XP as 232570.0/232570 :|

I'm setting up a local server with the same settings to experiment a bit...I'll be updating this question accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem with my config. In the first place, I misinterpreted the way XP is assigned in custom levels. I thought that the value represented the amount of XP required to level up when in fact it represents the total XP since level 1. So this means that if you want it to take 10 XP to go from level 90 to level 91 and if level 90 total XP required is 100, then to go from 91 to 92 with 10 XP you'd set the XP value of level 92 to be 110.

The other setting I was missing was OverrideMaxExperiencePointsPlayer. This setting had the value of 232570. So when I updated the requirements to go from 83 to 121 adding 1 XP for each of those levels (i.e. 232570, 232571, 232572,...) it didn't work because the OverrideMaxExperiencePointsPlayer setting was 232570. So I changed this value with the value of required XP of level 120.